# How to save data in text file using php

Tags: php

I need to save many variables in text file and later retrieve any one random data from the text document.

For Example ...i need to add **31231231** to the below text file

```
213123123
213123124
123412321
```

and i need to retrieve random value from above text file ..for example **213123124** from above text file

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filesystem.php

Comment: $handle = fopen("lol.txt", "a");
foreach($_GET as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");

Comment: i use the above code to get the value ...but i wonder how to retrieve the value from same txt document...that is random number

Comment: I am glad you are moving your career towards programming instead of singing. I think that's the best for all. Btw, you have a typo in your last name :)

Comment: Please add this (formatted) code to your question, it'll help you get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to the already existing file :

```
file_put_contents("file.txt","\n31231231",FILE_APPEND);
```

To get a random value from the file :

```
$file = file("file.txt")
$len = count($file);
$rand  = rand ( 0, $len-1 );
echo $file[$rand];
```

***Edit:*** While retrieving the PHP_EOL is included so do this:

<strike>`echo intval($file[$rand]);`</strike>

***Edit:*** Seeing as `intval()` returns the `max_int` for numbers that exceed int specs, just use `trim();`

```
echo trim($file[$rand])
```

Comment: oh thank you so much..this works..how can i put the numbers in new line next time...

Comment: @Sabari OK. Replace `\n` with the `PHP_EOL`constant. It works for me on windows though.

Comment: when i am getting back a value...it adds new line..how can i remove it

Comment: @JustinBiaber `echo intval($file[$rand]);`

Comment: its returning some garbage values :(

Comment: i have values in http://www.facebook.com.myfbapps.info/file.txt , but its returning 2147483647 which does not even exist

Answer (score 0):

To write in to a file you can use :

```
file_put_contents("test.txt","31231231".PHP_EOL ,FILE_APPEND);
```

Here PHP_EOL outputs \r\n or \n depending on the OS.

To select a random value from the text file you can use:

```
$file = file("test.txt")
$file_length = count($file);
$random_value  = rand ( 0, $file_length-1 );
echo $file[$random_value];
```

New Edit:

If you want to avoid new line at the retrieved output you can do :

```
echo intval($file[$random_value]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: when i am getting back a value...it adds new line..how can i remove it

Comment: Just change the last line to echo intval($file[$random_value]); You will get it correct. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To save and access variables and information when stored as text, in db or flat files, create array of the data first, then use serialize() on the data before saving, and unserialize() after fetching again. This allows for easy handling of information.

And remember to save many smaller files , rather than a large one...